# Rule engine in perl

Tags: perl

I am looking out for a rule engine in perl.

Would like to know what are the features, that should be kept in mind related to the same.

Also the context is a travel domain and the business rule related to it.

Would appreciate your views on the same.

Comment: may be this helps ? http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=722668

Comment: Haven't you read this? http://search.cpan.org/~gphat/Rule-Engine-0.06/lib/Rule/Engine.pm

Answer (score 1):

I believe your question is answered at http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=722668 and other places (google for Business Rule engine Perl). Some of the suggestions are:

- [PIE](http://www.pre-emptive.net/doco/pie-perl-inference-engine)
- [Bricks](http://www.slideshare.net/brian_d_foy/brick-business-rules-in-closures-kay) (could not find anything beyond this one site)
- [VS::RuleEngine](http://search.cpan.org/~claesjac/VS-RuleEngine-0.09/lib/VS/RuleEngine.pm)
- [Rule::Engine](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Rule-Engine/)

Comment: Ya i have visited the links, but what i need to know is what point should be kept in mind while selecting the RE.